# VS Code Debugger Immediately Exits

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I use VS Code for a python project but recently whenever I launch the debugger it immediately exits. The debug UI will pop up for half a second then disappear. I can't hit a breakpoint no matter where it's placed in the current file. The project has the expected normal behavior when run in non-debug mode. I vaguely remember a command being inserted into the terminal window when I used to click debug but now I see nothing. I opened a totally different project but debugger still exits immediately.

Any advice? Anywhere I can find logs for the debugger run?

My launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried: running app as admin, reinstalling vs code, reinstalling python extension, restarting app, restarting computer, disabling all non-essential extensions, deleting launch.json, launching a file with only print statement.

Comment: It would also be useful to know whether you are debugging a standalone script or whether you have set up a launch.json file, and you are running a particular configuration; if you are could you include the details of the configuration you are running. In any case, it would be good to see the output from the terminal (View > Terminal).

Comment: I put my launch.json in my original post. After launching VS code there is no change to the terminal when I start a debug run. I believe it usually pastes then executes a command in the terminal but this isn't happening

Comment: Can you tell me the python version you are using (not the python extension version)？

Comment: I am using conda version 4.511, python version 3.5.6.final.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please install Python 3.7 or later.

If you must use Python 3.6 or earlier, rollback the **Python** extension to version 2022.08.0.

[image: Screenshot of extension in VS Code with "Install Another Version..." highlighted from the "Uninstall" alternate menu]

[image: Screenshot of extension version list with "2022.8.1" and "2022.8.0" highlighted]

Comment: thanks, and here is the link https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19441